# rsync copy symbolic links files in root folder without copying symbolic links recursively within the root folders

Tags: rsync, backup, symlink

I am trying to set up a script for copying symbolic links folder data and my idea is to set up a single folder and to create several symlinks in this folder where the rsync will then copy the data within those directories:

```
/backups/local/
/backups/local/etc # symlink to /etc/
/backups/local/var  # symlink to /var/
/backups/local/home # symlink to /home/
```

This becomes an issue and concern that when the files are copied - now I have to worry about other symlinks further down the line. What I want to see happen is that it only processes the root directories symlinks to copy the next directories but any symlinks found within `/etc/` `/var/` or `/home/` are not also copied.

For testing I put another symlink to `/etc/` inside of `/home/` as `/home/etc` and with all the options I tried it copies `/home/etc/` each time and its full file contents.

I found and tried the following options thinking that these options might be what I was looking for:

```
rsync -avz -L [options] # i knew this would copy everything and it did.
rsync -avz -L --copy-unsafe-links [options] # copies all symlinks recursively still.
rsync -avz --copy-unsafe-links [options] # still copies all symlinks file/contents recursively
```

I tried the --copy-unsafe-links options since it says in the man-page that root sym-links are considered unsafe so I was thinking maybe it would only copy the root sym-links.

Answer (score 1):

thats because you use the option `-a` remember `-a = -rlptgoD` and you see that `-l --links` is activated, try this :

```
rsync -vzrptgoD -L SRCFOLDER DSTFOLDER
```